# Use arrow keys when switching applications with super + tab

Tags: shortcut-keys

When you switch Applications with `Super + tab` you can cycle forwards by holding down `super` and pressing tab. And you can cycle backwards by holding `super + shift` and pressing tab.

But is there a way to configure it so that you can use the arrow keys (`left` and `right`) while holding `super` to cycle backwards and forwards through the applications?

Mac OS has this feature and I can't stop doing it! It's quite quite handy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> as keybindings to switch through the Alt+Tab task switcher with following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab', '<Alt>Tab', '<Super>Right']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "['<Shift><Super>Tab', '<Shift><Alt>Tab', '<Super>Left']"
```

These keybindings are by default assigned to tiling the windows left and right, so you may want to change these keybindings, or at least disable them:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-left "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings toggle-tiled-right "['']"
```

To reset to defaults, replace "set" by "reset" and leave the final argument off in the above commands.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have a way to perform this exactly as you describe but if you place separate applications on different desktops, you can use `super+page up` and `super+page down` to change between desktops, and effectively between apps.