# Windows don't keep the same order in alt+tab

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys

My problem basically is the following: I wanted to change windows using the arrow keys + the super key, I managed to do it using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209239/use-arrow-keys-when-switching-applications-with-super-tab?newreg=e11b2f4d25f849429efc329386242338) question where I remapped the key bindings. The problem now for me is that when I switch applications they change their order and I would like to have them in a static order.

Here is an example, suppose this is the windows that show when you press alt+tab:

```
#using this application
   |
   V
window 1 | window 2 | window 3
```

If I switch to the window 2, when I press alt+tab again I will have the following configuration:

```
#using this application
   |
   V
window 2 | window 1 | window 3
```

Which for me it's kind of annoying since I can't memorize in what order the windows are if they keep changing all the time.

So I would like to know if I can change this dynamic switching.

(I'm using ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: You are right, it's placing the app you used last to the first place; actually, the entire row is ordered by how recent you used a window relative to the others.

Comment: To be honest it seems to make sense; this allows one to quickly switch back-and-forth between the two most-recently used windows, which is a very common need. This is a sensible default. Unfortunately however I don't see a way to configure it in the `org.gnome.shell` gsettings namespace... I for one am not a fan of gnome shell extensions, but in this case I would suggest searching for one which has the feature of making this configurable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is that it shows applications in most recently used order. The idea is that you always can switch quickly between the two last windows currently in use. You tab more, optionally looking at the icons if you need to switch to a third application you used earlier. It has worked this way since Windows 3.1 and possibly earlier, and changing that behavior would require a Gnome Shell extension or editing source code.

You could, however, use the `cycle-windows` function to achieve largely what you want:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows "['<Alt>Escape','<Super>Right']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows-backward "['<Shift><Alt>Escape', '<Super>Left']"
```

would add <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right/Left</kbd> in addition to the default keybindings to move to the next/previous window. First disable the default bindings of these keys as indicated in the [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209239/use-arrow-keys-when-switching-applications-with-super-tab?newreg=e11b2f4d25f849429efc329386242338).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @vanadium answer - `cycle-windows` is not the solution, because it also sorts windows by recent use, at least on Gnome 45 on Ubuntu 23.10.

This behavior is unusable for me. I want it work the same as "tabs" in ANY program - with predictable order of switching left/right.

You can use tilling window manager i3 which works like that. It's sad we can't have this in Gnome