# How to prevent Ubuntu to sort apps which are appeared by Alt+Tab?

Tags: 20.04

When I press Alt+Tab Ubuntu will show opened apps in last time access order. It's very annoying to make **n** switches to any app I need most often. And lets say I want to pin some apps at the most left side of that list. I assume that somewhere in Ubuntu must be a file with that sorting function, which is needed to be commented. But I don't know where is this file. Does anybody know?

Comment: What do you think of this? https://askubuntu.com/q/1320376/1157519